# Como pegar dados de uma página modal?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma página principal com um formulário simples:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label for="tipo">Tipo de sessão:</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
    <option value="1">opcao 1</option>
    <option value="2">opcao 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label for="data">Data:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="data" required>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
 Funcionario
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Funcionario">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Funcionario</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Selecionar...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tenho outra página que lista os itens de funcionários:

```
while ($sessao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<div class="media col-sm-6">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h2 class="mt-0">'.$sessao['nome'].'</h2>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="DEVERIA SELECIONAR AQUI.php?id='.$sessao['id'].'">Seleciona</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteFlor.php?id='.$sessao['id'].'">Excluir</a>
          </div>
        </div>';
}
?>
```

Como fazer pra primeira página abrir a segunda (sendo ela um MODAL) e na segunda página, ao selecionar o funcionário, ele ser exibido na primeira tela?

É provável que já tenha algo assim aqui na comunidade, mas como não sei o nome dessa técnica, estou fazendo a pergunta.

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi, você seleciona na pagina fixa, abre o modal, seleciona no modal e o resultado aparece na fixa?

Comment: Isso mesmo eles smith

Comment: usando `$.ajax()`, quando vc selecionar o funcionário, na função de retorno `success` vc insere os dados na página fixa.

Comment: e fecha o modal